# how to implement quality of service 1(QOS1) in netty for sending message in netty client server?

Tags: java, netty

I am making one chat app in which i am using netty client and server. Suppose, i am using java client to send message to netty server, how to implement QOS1 service using netty client server? suppose i use below java code from client to send message to netty server,

```
channel.writeAndFlush(uMessage);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have look into some projects declaring they do it:

- http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/netty-4.1/codec-mqtt/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/mqtt/MqttCodecUtil.java.shtml
- https://github.com/andsel/moquette